# react-native-svg not resolved | victory-native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to work with victory-native package for graph for `react-native` platform. I have installed both `victory-native` and `react-native-svg` with `--save` command. And then I also linked them with

`react-native link` but now when I do `react-native start` it throws the following error:

```
error: bundling failed: Error: While trying to resolve module `react-native-
svg` from file `/Users/keshav/projects/PropertyFinder/node_modules/victory-
native/lib/components/victory-primitives/line.js`, the package 
`/Users/keshav/projects/PropertyFinder/node_modules/react-native-svg/package.json` was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved 
(`/Users/keshav/projects/PropertyFinder/node_modules/react-native-svg/index.js`. Indeed, none of these files exist:

* `/Users/keshav/projects/PropertyFinder/node_modules/react-native-svg/index.js(.native||.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json)`
* `/Users/keshav/projects/PropertyFinder/node_modules/react-native-svg/index.js/index(.native||.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json)`
at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency 
(/Users/keshav/projects/PropertyFinder/node_modules/metro/src/node-
haste/DependencyGraph/ResolutionRequest.js:104:15)
```

```

My package.json:

```
"react": "16.3.0-alpha.2",
"react-native": "0.54.2",
"react-native-svg": "^6.3.0",
"react-navigation": "^1.5.7",
"simple-swizzle": "^0.2.2",
"superagent": "^3.8.2",
"victory-native": "^0.17.2"
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried `react-native start --reset-cache`? Might or might not help, usually it's the first thing I try.

Comment: Also check that the `node_modules/react-native-svg/index.js` file indeed exists - `npm` is known to occasionally screw up packages. If this is the problem, nuking your `node_modules` and running `npm install` (or `yarn`) again might help.

Comment: @jevakallio Yes the file exists. And --reset-cache also isn't helping :(

Comment: Interesting. Are you able to create a reproducible example of this? The module resolver seems to be resolving to the correct file, but the bundler is not picking it up.

Comment: @jevakallio I think if you can add victory-native package to any boilerplate project of react-native and install react-native-svg and do linking you can reproduce it. Thats exactly what I did. I was going through https://www.raywenderlich.com/178012/react-native-tutorial-building-android-apps-javascript and everything was working fine but then I wanted to test graphs and I installed this library. Thats when the problem started. I delete all node_modules and reinstalled everything from scratch. Still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem.But the different is i used the 'react-native-tab-navigator'.I've tried many times with different ways until i restarted Xcode and rebuilt the project.I hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but I had to modify my `metro.config.js` file as follows:

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  resolver: {
    sourceExts: ['js', 'jsx', 'ts', 'tsx'] 
  }
}
```

I think this is to help metro resolve paths beyond js, jsx, etc.